# Why am I able to import Vue template into an EJS file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, ejs, templating

I was working on an Express app that uses Vue.js from a CDN and EJS as the templating engine. I create some Vuejs 'components' and import them into my EJS templates as partials. I don't know how it works but it does, I am curious as to *why* or *how* it actually works. I'm not using any bundler or anything. I wonder if there are any performance drawbacks also. thanks.

the `batches.ejs`

```
<div id="vue-home">
  <main class="container">
        <batches-component
          v-bind:batches="<%= batches %>"
        ></batches-component>
  </main>
</div>

<!-- Importing Batches component as partial -->
<%- include('components/batches.vue') %>
```

This is `batches.vue`

```
<template type="x-template" id="batches-component">
  <div>
    <div id="if-batches" v-if="batches.length > 0">
        batches work!
     </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: EJS doesn't know that there's "Vue code" in those files, and doesn't care. It composes the final file based on the ejs templates and commands, then sends it to the browser. As long as the result that arrives in the browser is valid "Vue code", it'll work fine.

Comment: @ChrisG yes I get that EJS doesn't know. But the Browser doesn't run .vue code only HTML. I see that it 'compiles' the vue file and spits out the HTML equivalent. But who is doing this 'compilation'?

Comment: That is probably done client-side by Vue.js, exactly like here: https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/vue The fact that you can use "Vue code" in your HTML code has nothing to do with express or ejs. (and afaik, both the div and the template are valid HTML)

Comment: @ChrisG okay it is Vue that does it. But I'm not just writing Vue code. I am using a Vue file as an Ejs partial. I am importing this file and it is then converted to html by vue, before the page fully renders. Isn't that strange? It means I won't need Webpack or what...

Comment: Afaik you only need webpack if you use ES6 `import` and `export`.